# Starting a activity indicator in one specific cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have created a Activity indicator in the storyboard in my custom cell.

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.btnDownload.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btnDownload.addTarget(self, action: "downloadButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

in downloadButton(sender: AnyObject):

```
let button: UIButton = sender as UIButton;    
let i = NSIndexPath(forRow: button.tag, inSection: 0)
//customCell *cell = (customCell *)[(UITableView *)self.view cellForRowAtIndexPath:i]
//cell.actInd.startAnimating()
```

Here I would like to get the cell I'm in currently and startAnimating() the activity indicator. Is this the way to do it in obj c? If that is the case how do I rewrite this for Swift?

Kind regards

Comment: im not sure if setting the tag using indexPath.row is a good practice.. u might run into cell reuse issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by rewriting the obj c code I posted in the original question, it works. Thx for the replies anyway.

```
let cell = self.tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(i)as novelCell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the IBAction method to the cell class itself and also set the delegate as that class. That way you will be able to access the activity indicator property of the  corresponding cell easily